# Hidden Primary DNS NS records

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, dns-hosting

I am trying to setup a hidden primary DNS server and want to understand what should the right way to setup the SOA and NS records

The hidden primary DNS will then do zone transfer to the secondary DNS that will be authoritative and serving DNS requests

The hidden primary DNS service provider is requesting to setup vanity NS in the zonefile

I do not understand the reason for doing so - i don't mind exposing the authoritative nameservers (secondary DNS) for that zone

Can i just put the NS records as the secondary DNS nameservers in the hidden primary zonefile ?

Comment: i think that you should explain what you are trying to solve with this, update the question

Comment: updated with further explanation

Comment: still, you hiding details

Answer (score 0):

> Can i just put the NS records as the secondary DNS nameservers in the hidden primary zonefile ?

Yes. That is exactly how it is supposed to be done in fact.

Whatever is in `SOA` as MNAME is not relevant for normal resolution (only broken software look at it). It is sometimes the hidden primary nameserver (see `fr.` for example) but even so it might not resolve or resolve but not be available.

Note that primary/secondary is kind of useless terminology. It is not something visible from outside, from clients requesting data. The only thing that matters is the `NS` recordset that must match between both sides of the delegation cut point. For the outside querying clients, all nameservers listed in the `NS` recordset are the same and all are supposed to have a complete copy of the zone content, no matter how (between one of them being primary and other feeding them from it, or all of them feeding from another one not present in the `NS` recordset).

> The hidden primary DNS service provider is requesting to setup vanity NS in the zonefile

As you don't give a lot of details, you might want to just ask more to your DNS provider and understand what they want because obviously you depend on them.